# How to cache a Jsoup request with OkHttp in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jsoup, okhttp

Basically what I want to achieve is to cache to requests I make with Jsoup using OkHttp as the http client for the request

This is what I have already tried
for Okhttp client

```
var client = OkHttpClient()
val cacheSize = (APP_CACHE_SIZE).toLong()   // 20MB
        val myCache = Cache(appContext.cacheDir, cacheSize)
         client.newBuilder()
            .cache(myCache)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->   // Interceptor is for adding cache to the app
                var request = chain.request()
                val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
                    .maxStale(APP_CACHE_MAX_LIFETIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()
                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .cacheControl(cacheControl)
                    .build()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
            .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Then I make a new request using this client to use it with Jsoup

```
val request = Request.Builder().url("mylink.com").get()
val req = App.client.newCall(request.build())
val ongoingBody  = Jsoup.parse(req.execute().body!!.string())
```

I'm getting the result normally but the caching does not happen

I'm I doing it the wrong way ?